# pygame how to set animation to the right place and player's direction when both direction keys are pressed

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I'm making a pygame platformer and I'm currently working on sliding, that's when player is falling and colliding with a wall, pressing the button of the direction of the wall would cause player to slow down falling and have sliding animation.
1.My approach includes setting a self.onair variable and a self.sliding variable, the first one indicates if player is on air and the second one indicates if player is colliding with a wall. I just used the collision check, I think colliding is somehow different from 'being pressed against wall' but I don't know other ways. Now the issue is that when colliding with wall the player can slide on the opposite direction while both keys are pressed, weird.

2.Another issue, which is similar, is that when player is on the ground and both keys are pressed. Regardless of which key is pressed first the player always face right, could be the result that player is facing right at first.
3.At the star of the game if I just press spacebar the player will jump with no animation.
I guess the three questions are all direction-related and can be put together

here's my code, collision is fine

```py
class Player():
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.img_stand = pygame.image.load('D:\ThingThing\inthething\H stand.png')
        self.img_standL = pygame.image.load('D:\ThingThing\inthething\H standL.png')
        self.img_asc = pygame.image.load('D:\ThingThing\inthething\H asc.png')
        self.img_dsc = pygame.image.load('D:\ThingThing\inthething\H dsc.png')
        self.img_ascL = pygame.transform.flip(self.img_asc, True, False)
        self.img_dscL = pygame.transform.flip(self.img_dsc, True, False)
        self.img_slide = pygame.image.load('D:\ThingThing\inthething\H slide.png')
        self.img_slideL = pygame.transform.flip(self.img_slide,True,False)
        #walk animation
        self.images_right = []
        self.images_left = []
        self.index = 0
        self.counter = 0
        self.direction = 0
        self.onair = False
        self.jump_counter = 0
        self.sliding = False


        for num in range(1,17):
            img_right = pygame.image.load(f'D:\ThingThing\inthething\H walk{num}.png')
            self.images_right.append(img_right)

        for num in range(1,17):
            img_left = pygame.image.load(f'D:\ThingThing\inthething\H walkL{num}.png')
            self.images_left.append(img_left)

        self.image = self.img_stand
        self.width = self.image.get_width()
        self.height = self.image.get_height()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (x,y))
        self.hit_box = self.rect.copy()

        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.width = self.image.get_width()
        self.height = self.image.get_height()

        self.vel_y = 0
        self.jumped = False
    def update(self):
        dx = 0
        dy = 0
        walk_cooldown = 8



        #get key
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            dx += 1
            self.image = self.images_right[self.index]
            self.counter += 1
            # change size of self.rect
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midbottom=self.rect.midbottom)
            self.direction = 1

        elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            dx -= 1
            self.image = self.images_left[self.index]
            self.counter += 1
            # change size of self.rect
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midbottom=self.rect.midbottom)
            self.direction = -1







        if (key[pygame.K_LEFT] == False and key[pygame.K_RIGHT] == False) or (key[pygame.K_LEFT] == True and key[pygame.K_RIGHT] == True):
            self.counter = 0
            self.index = 0
            if self.direction == 1:
                self.image = self.img_stand


            elif self.direction == -1:
                self.image = self.img_standL
            dx = 0

            self.tempx = self.rect.centerx
            self.tempy = self.rect.bottom
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.centerx = self.tempx
            self.rect.bottom = self.tempy



        if self.counter > walk_cooldown:
            self.counter = 0
            self.index += 1
            if self.direction == 1:
                if self.index >= len(self.images_right):
                    self.index = 0
                self.image = self.images_right[self.index]
            if self.direction == -1:
                if self.index >= len(self.images_left):
                    self.index = 0
                self.image = self.images_left[self.index]

        if key[pygame.K_SPACE] and self.jumped == False:
            self.vel_y = -8
            self.jumped = True
            self.onair = True



        #jump + gravity
        self.vel_y += 0.3
        if self.vel_y > 10:
            self.vel_y = 10
        dy += self.vel_y





        #collide
        for tile in world.tile_list:

            if tile[1].colliderect(self.hit_box.x + dx, self.hit_box.y, self.width, self.height):
                if self.direction == -1:
                    self.image = self.img_standL
                if self.direction == 1:
                    self.image = self.img_stand
                self.sliding = True



                self.tempx = self.rect.centerx
                self.tempy = self.rect.bottom
                dx = 0
                self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
                self.rect.centerx = self.tempx
                self.rect.bottom = self.tempy

            if tile[1].colliderect(self.hit_box.x, self.hit_box.y + dy,self.width,self.height):

                if self.vel_y < 0:
                    dy = tile[1].bottom - self.hit_box.top
                    self.vel_y = 0
                elif self.vel_y > 0:
                    dy = tile[1].top - self.hit_box.bottom
                    self.vel_y = 0
                    self.jumped = False
                    self.onair = False
                    self.sliding = False
        if self.onair == True:
            if self.vel_y < 0  and self.sliding == False:
                if self.direction == 1:
                    self.image = self.img_asc
                    self.tempx = self.rect.centerx
                    self.tempy = self.rect.bottom
                    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
                    self.rect.centerx = self.tempx
                    self.rect.bottom = self.tempy
                if self.direction == -1:
                    self.image = self.img_ascL
                    self.tempx = self.rect.centerx
                    self.tempy = self.rect.bottom
                    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
                    self.rect.centerx = self.tempx
                    self.rect.bottom = self.tempy
            elif self.vel_y > 0 and self.sliding == False:
                if self.direction == 1:
                    self.image = self.img_dsc
                    self.tempx = self.rect.centerx
                    self.tempy = self.rect.bottom
                    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
                    self.rect.centerx = self.tempx
                    self.rect.bottom = self.tempy
                if self.direction == -1:
                    self.image = self.img_dscL
                    self.tempx = self.rect.centerx
                    self.tempy = self.rect.bottom
                    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
                    self.rect.centerx = self.tempx
                    self.rect.bottom = self.tempy

            if self.sliding == True and self.vel_y > 0:
                if self.direction == -1 and key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                    self.image = self.img_slide
                if self.direction == 1:
                    self.image = self.img_slideL
                self.sliding = True

                self.tempx = self.rect.centerx
                self.tempy = self.rect.bottom
                dx = 0
                self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
                self.rect.centerx = self.tempx
                self.rect.bottom = self.tempy






        #move

        self.rect.centerx += dx
        self.rect.bottom += dy
        self.hit_box.midbottom = self.rect.midbottom





        #onto screen
        screen.blit(self.image,self.rect)
        print(self.rect)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,255,255),self.rect,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The second problem you describe in your question is because you prioritize the right direction ( `if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]`). You must prioritize the case where both keys are pressed or both keys are not pressed, which can easily be tested with the condition `if key[pygame.K_RIGHT] == key[pygame.K_LEEFT]`:

```py
dx = 0
key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

if key[pygame.K_RIGHT] == key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    self.counter = 0
    dx = 0
    self.image = self.img_standL if self.direction == -1 else self.img_stand
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midbottom=self.rect.midbottom)

elif key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    self.counter += 1
    dx = 1
    self.direction = 1
    self.image = self.images_right[self.index]
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midbottom=self.rect.midbottom)

elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    self.counter += 1
    dx = -1
    self.direction = -1
    self.image = self.images_left[self.index]
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midbottom=self.rect.midbottom)
```